# Many to many relationships in SQL. Can t get more than one result

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, many-to-many

I'm designing a simple movie database. Point of it is to have 2 M:N relationships. 
So far I have design it like "central-base" database and it look like this.

```
GENRES(ID,GENRE_TYPE)- Many to many
ACTORS (ID, FULL_NAME, DOB) - many to many 
DESCRIPTIONS(ID,DESCRIPTION)
DIRECTORS(ID, FULL_NAME, DOB)
PROFITS(ID, AMOUNT)
BUDGETS(ID, AMOUNT)
MOVIES(ID, TITLE, LENGTH, YEAR, GENRE, CAST, BUDGET, PROFIT, DIRECTED_BY)** 
*those two are created to redefine M:N*
**MOVIE_GENRES(ID, MOVIE_ID, GENRE_ID)
MOVIE_CAST(ID, MOVIE_ID, ACTOR_ID)**
```

my question is when i do it like this, i'm only getting 1 actor per movie, or one genre per movie. 
The point is to have 2 actors for each movie, and 2 or 1 genre for each movie.

Since i m new one in field of sql please help me. I m using Oracle Live SQL.

qlq

Comment: Your design with two junctions tables for movies/actors and movies/genres looks fine. What makes you think that you are *only getting 1 actor per movie, or one genre per movie*?

Comment: Hi, thanks for an answer. I will explain.

Comment: So my goal is to make an database for movies as I said before. 
I ve created tables, i named FKs and at first everything seems fine but... The thing is when i want to for example to query data from other tables, let s say in this case I want to see what is genre from movie Godfather. That means that  I have to connect **Movies** with **Movie_genre** which is connected to **Genre**. My goal is to get for instance result:
Id 1
Title Godfather
length 2h 58min
....
**genre Drama Crime**
Which means 2 results.  All I m getting is just Drama.

Comment: OK then you have a question here. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59364136/edit) to add a [minimum reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) that demonstrates your problem so someone can actually look into it.

Comment: thank u, i m new here, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table for the genres:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Genres (
  ID   NUMBER(8,0)
       GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
       CONSTRAINT Genres__ID__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR2(30)
       CONSTRAINT Genres__Name__NN NOT NULL
       CONSTRAINT Genres__Name__U  UNIQUE
);
```

and you can insert sample data into it:

```sql
INSERT INTO Genres ( Name )
SELECT 'Comedy'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Horror'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Period Drama' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Documentary'  FROM DUAL
```

and a table for the people that contains the data specific to that person:

```sql
CREATE TABLE People (
  ID            NUMBER(8,0)
                GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                CONSTRAINT People__ID__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  FIRST_NAME    VARCHAR2(200)
                CONSTRAINT People__fn__nn NOT NULL,
  LAST_NAME     VARCHAR2(200)
                CONSTRAINT People__ln__nn NOT NULL,
  DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE
                CONSTRAINT People__dob__nn NOT NULL
);
```

Those people can take various roles in a film so create a table to describe the roles a person can take:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Roles (
  ID   NUMBER(8,0)
       GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
       CONSTRAINT Roles__ID__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  ROLE VARCHAR2(30)
       CONSTRAINT Roels__Role__NN NOT NULL
       CONSTRAINT Roles__Role__U  UNIQUE
);
```

for example:

```sql
INSERT INTO Roles ( Role )
SELECT 'Actor'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Director' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Producer' FROM DUAL;
```

This way you don't need to create a new table for each role a person takes on in the movie.

Then you can create a table with only the data that is specific to the movie (and not related to any of the other tables):

```sql
CREATE TABLE Movies (
  ID            NUMBER(8,0)
                GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                CONSTRAINT Movies__ID__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  TITLE         VARCHAR2(300)
                CONSTRAINT Movies__title__nn NOT NULL,
  LENGTH        INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  RELEASE_DATE  DATE,
  BUDGET        NUMBER(12,2),
  PROFIT        NUMBER(12,2)
);
```

Then you can create tables that describe the relationships between the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Movie_People (
  ID            NUMBER(8,0)
                GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                CONSTRAINT Movie_People__ID__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  Movie_ID      NUMBER(8,0)
                CONSTRAINT Movie_People__Movie_ID__NN NOT NULL
                CONSTRAINT Movie_People__Movie_ID__FK REFERENCES Movies( ID ),
  Role_ID       NUMBER(8,0)
                CONSTRAINT Movie_People__Role_ID__NN NOT NULL
                CONSTRAINT Movie_People__Role_ID__FK REFERENCES Roles( ID ),
  Person_ID     NUMBER(8,0)
                CONSTRAINT Movie_People__Person_ID__NN NOT NULL
                CONSTRAINT Movie_People__Person_ID__FK REFERENCES People( ID ),
  CONSTRAINT Movie_People__M_R_P__U UNIQUE( Movie_ID, Role_ID, Person_ID )
);
```

and

```sql
CREATE TABLE Movie_Genres (
  ID            NUMBER(8,0)
                GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                CONSTRAINT Movie_Genres__ID__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  Movie_ID      NUMBER(8,0)
                CONSTRAINT Movie_Genres__Movie_ID__NN NOT NULL
                CONSTRAINT Movie_Genres__Movie_ID__FK REFERENCES Movies( ID ),
  Genre_ID      NUMBER(8,0)
                CONSTRAINT Movie_Genres__Genre_ID__NN NOT NULL
                CONSTRAINT Movie_Genres__Genre_ID__FK REFERENCES Genres( ID ),
  CONSTRAINT Movie_Genres__M_G__U UNIQUE( Movie_ID, Genre_ID )
);
```

Then if you want to add an actor for a movie to the database:

```
INSERT INTO Movie_People (
  Movie_ID,
  Role_ID,
  Person_ID
) VALUES (
  ( SELECT ID FROM Movies WHERE title = 'The Muppet Christmas Carol' ),
  ( SELECT ID FROM Roles  WHERE role  = 'Actor' ),
  ( SELECT ID FROM People WHERE first_name = 'Michael' AND last_name = 'Caine' )
)
```

and if you want to find the movies with multiple genres then, for example:

```sql
SELECT Movie_ID
FROM   Movie_Genres
WHERE  Genre_ID IN (
  SELECT ID
  FROM   Genres
  WHERE  Name IN ( 'Comedy', 'Horror' )
)
GROUP BY Movie_ID
HAVING COUNT( Genre_ID ) = 2;
```

Comment: Thank u a lot, this saved me